# MySQL Replication using SSL

Tags: mysql, replication, ssl

I am in the process of replicating my database so i can have a  master slave configuration, one of the issues i have is with security i am basically generating my server/client keys and certificates using openssl i also generate my own CA key and certificate to self sign, i understand the issues with self signing certificates on a public website, but do you think this will be as a serious problem when used in replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem in public websites because you can't email your shiny new CA key to everybody on the Internet.  So instead by convention browsers ship with a small list of CAs (Verisign and friends) and we all buy certificates from them.

In database replication, you **can** visit both servers and install your new CA key.  As long as you trust you, and you don't **want** strangers to authenticate to your database, you're probably in the clear.